# Jest test all filename with *.test.tsx except filename that is data.test.tsx

Tags: jestjs, glob, ts-jest

I needed help with a jest, I want to test all file in folder that has pattern `*.test.{ts|tsx}` except `data.test.{ts|tsx}`.
I am having difficulties doing this.

This is the pattern that I use to match everything with `.package.json`

```
"testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
```

However I cannot find pattern to exclude `data.test.{ts|tsx}`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the reverse condition operator - `!` to exclude a special file. Then your configuration will look like this:

```
"testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!**/data.test.{ts,tsx}" // this line
    ],
```

Comment: Sorry, apparently the above code does not work